# How to set Kile livepreview to XeLaTeX as default (instead of PdfLaTeX)?

Tags: xetex, kile, live-preview

When I open new files (with automatic kile-livepreview launch) PdfLaTex is used and I have to switch manually to XeLaTeX.

How to set XeLaTeX as default for kile-livepreview ?

I saw for already opened files `kile_livePreviewTool=LivePreview-XeLaTeX` in `kilerc` but don't find the general parameter.

Thank you for help

Comment: Have you tried setting the default QuickBuild to XeLaTeX? Note that I have live preview disabled, so this is just a suggestion of what I might try.

Comment: Yes my quickbuild already use XeLaTeX. The question is only for le live preview

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9sm6ay/kile_is_it_possible_to_change_compiler_in_live/ ? It is quite old, but there is a (somewhat) more recent comment at the bottom which might be helpful ....

Comment: This is only for quickbuild (my computer is set as in this link) but not for live-preview.

Comment: A work around for me is to set in `.kilerc` `[Tool/LivePreview-PDFLaTeX/Default]` with `command=xelatex` and `options=-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%dir_target %source` as in `[Tool/LivePreview-XeLaTeX/Default]`